# I am trying to add a PYTHONPATH to environment variable on the terminal. But several ways won't work for me

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables

Want to import package from the current directory but changing ./bashrc won't work

Environment: macOS catalina version 10.15 Beta
shell seems to be updated to zsh.
Have both python2 and python3 installed.
I tried to add PYTHONPATH in several environment variable files as many online user suggested. But none of those works works.

However, I tried to use

```sh
python3 -c "import sys; sys.append("path/to/package")
```

It onlyworks temporarily while python program is running.

[image: python environment path]

I expected to add package path. However, it's still the same.

Comment: How are you adding PYTHONPATH to the environment? Don't forget to use ```export``` i.e export PYTHONPATH=...

Comment: I tried add modify several files. ~/.bashrc ~/.zshrc ~/.bash_profile. Finally, typing EXPORT directly in the terminal works.

Comment: Ok. First you need to find which shell you are using. Type ```echo $0``` in your terminal. If the output is ```-zsh``` then edit the ```~/.zhrc``` and add ```export PYTHONPATH=....``` if its ```-bash``` then use the add the above in the ```~/.bash_profile```

Comment: Just like @maitreyak says. Remember to source the edited file or restart terminal to enable the exported `PYTHONPATH` environment.